# Not able to remove all whitespace characters in PostgreSQL string using regexp_replace or replace functions

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I am having werid problem. Trying to remove whitespace characters from varchar variable in PostgresSQL. However one space is not removed. I dont know how is this possible.

Variable value: `Snímek obrazovky 2019-12-05 v 13.33.37.png`

```
regexp_replace(variable, '\s', '_', 'g')
```

Returns: `Snímek_obrazovky_2019-12-05_v 13.33.37.png` (notice a space after _v)

```
replace(variable, ' ', '_')
```

Returns: `Snímek_obrazovky_2019-12-05_v 13.33.37.png` = the same.

I dont know what else to try. Any ides? Might be some special character in there? Can identify which kind.

Comment: Try `[[:space:]]+`

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZO4ImHLp

Comment: Yes it works is Fiddle. I believe there must be some special character in my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UTF8 encoding you can check the codes of all characters in the string:

```sql
select ch, ascii(ch) as code
from unnest(regexp_split_to_array('Snímek obrazovky 2019-12-05 v 13.33.37.png', '')) as ch
```

Comment: AHA!! Thank you! It was "no brake space" character 160 instead of 32 regular space. Looks like \s doesnt cover that.

Answer (score 0):

```
replace(variable,chr(160),'_')
```

Is the way to go.